# unable to vertically align the two buttons at the top

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

In a table with one row where the first and second column having widths 20% and 60% respectively following is the *html* in that row of the second column. There is a browse button and a submit button. I want both of them to get vertically aligned at the top. I have mentioned this in css but I do not see the desired result. What could be the reason for this ?

*Html snippet :*

```
                <form method="post" action="#">
                 <div id="Files_to_be_shared"> 
                       <input type="file" id="File" name="FileTag" />
                       <input type="submit" value="Share" /> 
                 </div>
                </form>
```

*Corresponding css snippet:*

```
#Files_to_be_shared {
    color:#FFEC94;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

This is the output I see *(and I have marked where I want it to get placed)*:

[image]

Comment: text-align:center ; will do this

Comment: @NullPointer no it won't.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `table` then add `valign="top"` to the `td`

& add `align="center"` to align it to the center of the `td`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wKzEF/3/)**

---

or try this

```
    #Files_to_be_shared {
      color:#FFEC94;
      vertical-align:top; 
      text-align:center 
    }
    td{
     border:1px solid grey; 
     vertical-align:top;
    }
```

​

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/wKzEF/6/)**

Comment: but what is the problem with the css ?

Comment: nothing, just dont recommend a deprecated attribute, valign is really old, and mixing old inline attr with css is odd at least